# How to add Request Samples of PHP and C# in Django ReDoc

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I am using drf-yasg package for my Django Rest API Documentation.
By default It showing only one Request sample called "Payload" like shown in below link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pno2.jpg
I want to Add More Request Sample like shown in the picture below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy9tv.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it if you rewrite method *get_operation* from *SwaggerAutoSchema* class.

```
from drf_yasg.inspectors import SwaggerAutoSchema

class CustomAutoSchema(SwaggerAutoSchema):

    def get_operation(self, operation_keys=None):
        operation_keys = operation_keys or self.operation_keys

        consumes = self.get_consumes()
        produces = self.get_produces()

        body = self.get_request_body_parameters(consumes)
        query = self.get_query_parameters()
        parameters = body + query
        parameters = filter_none(parameters)
        parameters = self.add_manual_parameters(parameters)

        operation_id = self.get_operation_id(operation_keys)
        summary, description = self.get_summary_and_description()
        security = self.get_security()
        assert security is None or isinstance(security, list), "security must be a list of security requirement objects"
        deprecated = self.is_deprecated()
        tags = self.get_tags(operation_keys)

        responses = self.get_responses()

        return openapi.Operation(
            operation_id=operation_id,
            description=force_real_str(description),
            summary=force_real_str(summary),
            responses=responses,
            parameters=parameters,
            consumes=consumes,
            produces=produces,
            tags=tags,
            security=security,
            deprecated=deprecated,
            **{'x-code-samples': self.overrides.get('code_examples')}
        )
```

Then you can use this schema in your view

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    swagger_schema = CustomAutoSchema
```

and add decorator to your view methods:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(
        code_examples=[
            {
                'lang': 'bash',
                'source': 'curl -H "Authorization: Token YOUR-API-KEY" https://developers.typless.com/api/document-types/'
            },
        ]
    )
```

You can read more on [this blog.](https://jangiacomelli.com/redoc-code-examples-in-drf-using-drf-yasg/)